# Listpicker tap event in fullscreen mode not working correctly

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listpicker

I'm developing windows phone 8 application.

I'm using ListPicker option.

**My Listpicker code**

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="LPfilter" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0"  Margin="300,0,0,0"  Height="80" Width="50" Visibility="Visible">
            <toolkit:ListPicker.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Images/filters.png"/>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.Background>

            <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"   Visibility="Collapsed" Foreground="Red"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>

            <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Tap="TextBlock_Tap">
                        <Run Text="{Binding name}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

values bind to listpicker using webservice (json format).

Json result comes like this

```
[
  -{
     id: "9",
     name: "Pizza",
     root_id: "4",
     level: "1",
   },

  -{
     id: "10",
     name: "Fine Dinind",
     root_id: "4",
     level: "1",
   },

  -{
      id: "11",
      name: "Fast Food",
      root_id: "4",
      level: "1",
   },
    ....
]
```

**c# code for bind values**

```
public void businesscatbind()
    {

            string bus_caturl = "http://xxxxx.com/Service/filterquery.php?rootid=" + bus_catval;
            WebClient bus_catwc = new WebClient();

            bus_catwc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(bus_caturl), UriKind.Relative);
            bus_catwc.DownloadStringCompleted += bus_catwc_DownloadStringCompleted;
    }

 void bus_catwc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bus_catdata = e.Result;
        var bus_catvalue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<bus_catbinddata>>(bus_catdata);
        LPfilter.ItemsSource = bus_catvalue;
     }
```

**Problem occur in this event**

```
    private void TextBlock_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        bus_catbinddata elements = LPfilter.SelectedItem as bus_catbinddata;
        int val = LPfilter.SelectedIndex;

        filterid = int.Parse(elements.id);
        MessageBox.Show(filterid.ToString());
     }
```

My problem

First time i click pizza it's show the value = Id value 9 in msgbox

next i click Fine Dining it's show the value = Id value 9 in msgbox

next i click Fast Food it's show the value =10 in msgbox (10 Is the idvalue of  FineDining)

next i click Italian it's show the value = 11 in msgbox (11 is the Idvalue of Fastfood)

previews selected item value is show in alert

**Output**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you verify if the SelectedItem value had changed?

Comment: @Vasanth Sriram i'm not clear what you ask...

Answer (score 0):

Use Listpicker SelectionChanged event instead

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="LPfilter" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0"  Margin="300,0,0,0"  Height="80" Width="50" Visibility="Visible" SelectionChanged="listPicker_SelectionChanged>
```

Comment: If i use selection changed event it's call on page load twice automatically

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the "TextBlock_Tap" event fires up before the "ListPicker" changes its selection.

You can try to use the "SelectionChanged" event of the ListPicker - although it seems that you are not using it because you might want to select the same option twice. In that case, you can add a dummy item to the top of your list saying something like "Select Item" and in the "SelectionChanged" event in the end set the selected item of list picker to your dummy item.

EDIT:

In this method -

```
void bus_catwc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var bus_catdata = e.Result;
    var bus_catvalue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<bus_catbinddata>>(bus_catdata);
    LPfilter.ItemsSource = bus_catvalue;
 }
```

add a new "bus_catbinddata" to the "var bus_catvalue" - it is a list - insert your dummy itme at index 0. then in selection changed event of list picker, add a condition if(ListPicker.SelectedIndex > 0) and only if this condition is true, the code will execute.

Comment: If there is any way to use Textblock_tap event with out selection changed event

Comment: @Gurunathan as I said, the Tap event fires before the selection changes. I don't know anyway you can change the order of these events occuring. Why exactly do you need the Tap event?

Answer (score 0):

in Xaml page

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="listPicker" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0"  Margin="300,0,0,0"  Height="80" Width="50" Visibility="Visible" SelectionChanged="listPicker_SelectionChanged" >
        <toolkit:ListPicker.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Images/filters.png"/>
        </toolkit:ListPicker.Background>

        <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"   Visibility="Collapsed" Foreground="Red"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>

        <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Tap="TextBlock_Tap">
                    <Run Text="{Binding name}"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

In .cs File

```
 void listPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {

        if (this.listPicker.SelectedItems != null && this.listPicker.SelectionMode == SelectionMode.Multiple)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.listPicker.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
            {
                string str = ((Items)(this.listPicker.SelectedItems[i])).Name;
                if (i == 0)
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("Selected Item(s) is " + str);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Some Code
                }
            }
        }
        else if (this.listPicker.SelectionMode == SelectionMode.Single)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Selected Item is " + ((Items)this.listPicker.SelectedItem).Name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this specifically with `ListPicker`'s full mode item template, but you can try to get corresponding model for tapped `TextBlock` from `DataContext` :

```
private void TextBlock_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock textBlock = (TextBlock)sender;
    bus_catbinddata elements = textBlock.DataContext as bus_catbinddata;

    filterid = int.Parse(elements.id);
    MessageBox.Show(filterid.ToString());
 }
```